# Is it possible to optimise and resize an image with mozjpeg?

Tags: jpeg, image-processing

I want to be able to compress and resize and image with [mozjpeg's](https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg) `cjpeg` command

However according to [the usage file](https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg/blob/master/usage.txt) it does not seem like  `cjpeg` can do both in one single command.

Is it right?

If it is impossible to both compress and resize at the same time, should I use `jpegtran` to perform the resize function? If I should use  `jpegtran`, then should the resize before or after the `cjpeg` optimises?

Comment: Perhaps I am blind, but in the usage page you link to, neither `cjpeg` nor `jpegtran` seem to have a `resize` option? The closest thing I spotted was `djpeg`, which has a `scale` option, but that's for decompressing `.jpg` images.

Comment: then how can one use this toolset to scale down a jpeg image?

Comment: It seems likely you would need to use `djpeg` with the `scale` option to turn the image into e.g. a bitmap of the size you wanted, then use `cjpeg` to recompress that e.g. bitmap into a `.jpg` format.

Comment: Looks like it is a no-go because `djpeg` is not *is not tested and not maintained.* https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg/issues/309#issuecomment-440674126

Comment: Ah. That's too bad. =/

Comment: @AnthonyKong, have you consider to change the base and use ImageMagic?